# Laravel and vue js in deployment

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi how can i upload my laravel + vue js project in 000webhost i choose this because its free. I have zero experience on deployment i just want to upload my work on ther internet nevermind the security issues. This is for my first portfolio project. Can someone atleast guide me on how to. I watched some tutorials on how to upload laravel projects and didnt see laravel + vue deployment. Is it the same or it will be more complicated and need more configuration because of the added vue js? Thanks for all your help i know this is stupid question but Im just a beginner in web dev and still learning and this will be a huge knowledge for me if i successfully uploaded my project. Thank you guys.

Comment: You need ssh@ access for that and shared webhosting not good for backend application like laravel --i am not saying it's impossible-- not recommended...

Comment: Thanks sir can you suggest an alternative way?

Comment: an alternative way, you still deploy vue app into shared hosting no problem with that. and for backend I recommend custom rest api crud with php...

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment so I have to leave this as an answer
StackOverflow isn't meant for questions like this. To help, you can have a look at this blogpost:
[Deploy Laravel on Shared hosting](https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6)

It is however not recommended to deploy Laravel on a shared hosting server. You can get a cheap SSH server from Linode or Digital Ocean.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have zero knowledge on deployment thats why i found this very hard. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Does your blog will apply to a laravel + vue app??